# Modify array before sending to the user

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently working on a bot project and stuck in some line of codes.
What I'm trying to do is convert the user input into an array and then modify it before sending it back to the user.

It's like

```
user=> hello
bot => :indicator_h::indicator_e::indicator_l::indicator_l::indicator_o:
```

As you can see, the letter after `_` are based on user input `:indicator_{userinput#1}` and then adds another `:` at the end.
I'm using `split()` to convert user's input into array. I've made the bot send `:indicator_h:`, but it only worked for a single word, when I send more than one characters, it will send `:indicator_h,e,l,l,o:` instead of separate 'em.

I don't know how to ask this properly since my English is not that good, and maybe someone already asked about this. If so, please give me a link to that thread before marking this question as a duplicate. :)

Thank you in Advanced,
Cheers!

Comment: It's a little bit unclear what you need. Do you want your bot to send data to the user like this `:indicator_h::indicator_e::indicator_l::indicator_l::indicator_o:` ?

Comment: It's hard to help you without any code

Comment: Please add the code you have. It would be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```js
var s = "hello world"
console.log(s.split("").filter(v=> v!==" ").map(i=>":indicator_" + i + ":").join(""))
```

Comment: totally the most simple one!
every answer is working, but this one is simple, thank you so much :)

Comment: sorry, but how do i make it ignores spaces? tried many ways but i'm too new for this `:(` 
like it'll send `:indicator_ :` instead of just blank space if theres a space
i tried regex as well, but yeah still no idea how to make it.

Answer (score 1):

`input_massage` creates an array of letters out of the user's input. Then iterates through each letter and converts it to `:indicator_{userinput#1}:`. Then converts it back to a string for the bot.

```js
function input_massage(input) {
  return input.split('')
              .map(function(letter) {
                 return `:indicator_${letter}:`
              })
              .join('');
}

console.log(input_massage('hello'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the input string (`"hello"`) into individual characters, use the [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform each of the elements into the corresponding indicator, and then join all the modified elements into one string.

```
function toIndicators(str) {
    return str.split("").map(char => `:indicator_${char}:`).join("");
}

toIndicators("hello"); // => ":indicator_h::indicator_e::indicator_l::indicator_l::indicator_o:"
```

The `split("")` call converts the string into an array containing all the individual characters.

The `map` call executes the provided function on all of the elements of the array (all of the characters). The function passed to map inserts the single character into the correct position in the indicator template string.

The `join("")` call concatenates all the elements of the array into one string with no delimiter between them.